# Create EventBridge Filter for a triggered event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I have the following event that sends an email.  I want to filter this out since it's a routine call that happens across all regions.  I am having no luck anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong:

**Alert sample**

> {    "Account ID":   "80xxxxxxxxxx",   "AWS Region":   "us-east-1",
> "User ARN":
> "arn:aws:sts::80xxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/my-team-read/logstash",
> "User Agent":   "[aws-sdk-ruby2/2.11.632 jruby/2.6.8 java resources]",
> "Source IP":    "11.111.111.111",
> "Event Time":   "2023-06-21T06:51:57Z",   "
> Event Source": "s3.amazonaws.com",
> "Event Type":   "AwsApiCall",   "Event Name":   "GetObject",
> "Parameters": ["production-logging","production-logging.s3.amazonaws.com","cloudtrail/AWSLogs/80xxxxxxxxxx/CloudTrail/ap-southeast-1/2023/06/21/80xxxxxxxxxx_CloudTrail_ap-southeast-1_20230621T0610Z_XXXXXXXXXX.json.gz"]
>
> }

**MY JSON FILTER**

```
{
    "source": [
        "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "userIdentity": {
            "type": [
                "AssumedRole"
            ],
            "arn": {
                "not": {
                    "contains": [
                        "my-team-read/logstash"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind I want to filter anyone of these alerts regardless of the region.

Answer (score 0):

Closing loop here.  This is what we did:

```
{
    "source": ["aws.s3"],
    "detail": {
        "eventName": [
            { "anything-but": ["GetObject"] }
        ],
        "userIdentity": {
            "type": ["AssumedRole"],
            "arn": {
                "not": { "prefix": "arn:aws:sts::80xxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/my-team-read/logstash" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked for a very basic filter.